# db2ReadLog API db2ApiDf.h - installation and how to use

Tags: database, db2

We're trying to use db2ReadLog API to read logs from a file and update abinitio server. To begin with, we need to install and know how to use. I 've searched and couldn't get the installables and no guide on how to properly use it. Any suggestions on this is welcome

Comment: Generally this will run on the database server, where the log files are located - which will also have includes/libraries. Have you read the [documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.api.doc/doc/r0001673.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-3-3-62) or looked at the [code samples](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/c/s-dblogconn-sqc.html?lang=en-us) for `db2ReadLog`?

Comment: Yes @IanBjorhovde. In what version/ type of DB release does this API comes? Should I have to buy enterprise edition or something? And,is there a guide that explains how to install this in linux, which path i should place them etc.,. ? Also, I read that 'db2ApiDf.h' to work, we need the associated system object - '.so' files? where / how do I get those files? Sorry there's a lot of questions that I ask all necessarily means same thing (almost) :)